# How do I make "bash -x" (debug mode) recurse into sourced scripts?

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I'm trying to debug what bash does on login initialization for Linux. I've read that "bash -x" will make bash print out what it's doing, but it doesn't print commands in sourced files like "set -x" does. I can't use "set -x" because initialization runs before I can call it. "bash -x" seems to recurse fine on OS X, but that might be because of the bash versions.

Linux: 3.2.25

OS X: 3.2.48

Here's an excerpt of the non-recursing behavior on Linux:

```
bash -l -x -c 'echo 1'
# ... snip ...
+ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/vim.sh ']'
+ '[' '' ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/vim.sh
+ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/which-2.sh ']'
+ '[' '' ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/which-2.sh
# ... snip ...
```

Notice how /etc/profile.d/vim.sh is sourced, but its commands aren't printed.
Is there a workaround without upgrading? Is this caused by the version difference?

Answer (score 1):

`set -x` somewhere in the root file (the one requiring all other files) should work. Alternatively, introduce something like `[[ !-z "$DEBUG" ]] && set -x` in each file, and call with `DEBUG=1 script.sh`.

Comment: Where is the root file? Is it platform independent?

Comment: With "root file" I simply mean the file you are calling on the shell, and which is importing the other files. In my example, the root file would be script.sh

Comment: But bash login initialization happens before the script is run. It's too late to run "set -x" in the script. Try it yourself - run "bash -l -x script.sh". You'll see stuff happening before your script's commands are run.

Comment: Why on Earth would you run a script with `bash -l`? That's meant for interactive shells. A script is not an interactive shell.

Comment: Please be a bit more open-minded - obviously the creators of bash thought it would be useful. I see 2 uses (at least): 1) You want to run `ssh user@host 'bash -l -c command'` so you get the proper env loaded. 2) You're a sysadmin and want to *troubleshoot* what init scripts are doing *before* your script runs - `bash -l -x` will show you. Sometimes you want to know where an env variable is being set.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sourcing scripts and not executing, your first command in the main script should be "set -x"

Now all sourced scripts will run in debug more. Remember when you source a script, it runs in you current shell, so if you set -x once, that will be good for all sources scripts.